# In Isolate. Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make my app more faster. So I am going to use isolate. But I got this error

```
fetchData() async {
  urlIsolate = await Isolate.spawn(_fetchUrl, recievePort.sendPort);
   recievePort.listen((message) {
     print(message);
    });
  SendPort sendPort = await recievePort.first;
}
```

```
static _fetchData(SendPort sendPort) async {
    sendPort.send('message');
  }
```

When I use `recievePort.listen((message) {print(message); });` I got this error...

```
E/flutter (20567): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
E/flutter (20567): #0      _StreamController._subscribe (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:710:7)
E/flutter (20567): #1      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:861:19)
E/flutter (20567): #2      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:493:9)
E/flutter (20567): #3      _ReceivePortImpl.listen (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:89:31)
E/flutter (20567): #4      Stream.first (dart:async/stream.dart:1294:14)
E/flutter (20567): #5      DataFetchController.fetchUrl (package:email_collector/services/data_fetching_controller.dart:15:43)
E/flutter (20567): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are listening on `recievePort` twice. First with `listen` and then with `first`. `first` is a subscription which will return the first event and then close the stream.

Also, how is `recievePort` defined? The last line does not make much sense since you are sending a `String` on your `sendPort` in your isolate so `recievePort.first` will never return a `SendPort` instance?